Struct of vectors passed as argument in a lib function has weird behaviour
I use a library in my code : mapping2D
All compile and seems to link well.
Trying to call a function from that lib:
#include "Mapper.h"
[...]
PointsData points;
// Filling 3 points with x,y,z
[...]
std::unique_ptr<Surface> surface = Mapper::calculateSurface(&points, m_surfaceSettings, mesh);

The problem is that when I run debugger, with a break point at this called function, the points seems to be well structured :

but when I'm entering the function (F11) :

the vectors of my objects are not the same at all, very weird behaviour, and random number of elements in y at each execution :

If I continue I crash with "vector too long" :

PointsData struct in the library is defined like that
struct PointsData
{
    std::vector<double> x;
    std::vector<double> y;
    std::vector<double> z;
};

I tryed a lot of things, but I don't really know what's happening (knowing that the creator of the library made code for an application to use his library, I compiled that and it works well)
Somebody has an idea to get me out of that problem ?
EDIT : for more accuracy of my question, here is the code between PointData and calculateSurface
SequenceIsochronousAggregate &SequenceIsochronousAggregate::computeIsochronous(const HoleBottomPositionsAndDelaysMap &positionsMap, int linesNb, bool useSavedData)
{
    int nbEntryPointsVal = positionsMap.size();
    if(nbEntryPointsVal < 3)
        return *this;
        
    _data.isolinePointsMap().clear();

    PointsData points;
    
    // Defining isoline min and max values, used to split number of lines
    _savedIsoMaxValue = _savedIsoMinValue = positionsMap.first().second;
    std::vector<cgal::CGPoint2> pointsAsCgal;
    for(auto posValPair : positionsMap)
    {
        if(posValPair.second < _savedIsoMinValue)
            _savedIsoMinValue = posValPair.second;

        if(posValPair.second > _savedIsoMaxValue)
            _savedIsoMaxValue = posValPair.second;

        // Also filling the cgal points vector in order to compute ConvexHull
        pointsAsCgal.push_back(cgal::CGPoint2(posValPair.first.x(),posValPair.first.y()));

        // Also defining points data in mapping2D format
        points.x.push_back(posValPair.first.x());
        points.y.push_back(posValPair.first.y());
        points.z.push_back(0.);
    }

    // Computing the ConvexHull (aka, area points that contains all holes)
    auto convexAsCgal = cgal::ConvexHull2D(pointsAsCgal);
    auto convexAsQPoints = cgal::CGPoint2ToQPointF(convexAsCgal);
    if(convexAsQPoints.size() < 3)
        return *this;
    QPolygonF shapePoly;
    for(auto p : convexAsQPoints)
        shapePoly << p;
    _data.setShapePolygon(shapePoly);

    QRectF holesRectArea = shapePoly.boundingRect();
    _data.setBoundaryRect(holesRectArea);

    // Computing mesh
    Point originPointMesh;
    originPointMesh.x = holesRectArea.topLeft().x();
    originPointMesh.y = holesRectArea.topLeft().y();
    RegularMesh2d mesh(originPointMesh, MESH_RESOLUTION, MESH_RESOLUTION, holesRectArea.width()/MESH_RESOLUTION, holesRectArea.height()/MESH_RESOLUTION, 0.0);

    std::unique_ptr<Surface> surface = Mapper::calculateSurface(&points, m_surfaceSettings, mesh);

    MarchingSquares marchSqrIsoliner(surface.get());
    std::vector<std::pair<double, Isoline>> isolines = marchSqrIsoliner.calculate(_savedIsoMinValue, _savedIsoMaxValue, linesNb - 1, (_savedIsoMaxValue - _savedIsoMinValue) / (double)(linesNb - 1));

    for(auto valIsolinePair : isolines)
    {
        int val = (int)valIsolinePair.first;
        for(auto point : valIsolinePair.second.getPoints())
        {
            data::IsolineData<int>::IsolinePointInfo isoPointInfo(QPointF(point.x,point.y),val,0.f);
            _data.appendPoint(val,isoPointInfo);
        }
    }

    this->appendChange(new SequenceIsochronousChangedEvent(uuid(), _data));
    return *this;
}

EDIT2 : However, this minimal code produces the same problem...
Knowing also that I rebuild all in debug, no trace of release of any lib because never built in release.
Knowing also that the main code is also in a lib (called domain) of the general app

Are you mixing debug and release builds of your application vs the library, by accident? That typically manifests as oddities in containers. Also, is the code at the top of your question inside a function or at the top level? Edit your question to a [mre].

@Botje thank you for your response.
The code at the top in part off another lib (called domain) of the application
The cmakelist of domain countains
set(DEPENDENCIES mapping2d) create_static_library("${MODULE_NAME}" "${MODULE_SOURCES}" "${QT_COMPONENTS}" "${DEPENDENCIES}")

Additionnaly, I all clear and all recompile (compiling mapping also) in debug, so I think their is no risk using release version of mapping2d lib (knowing that I never compiled my project in release for now)

The only other thing I can think of is stack corruption. But for that you will have to show the code inbetween the creation of pointsData and the call to calculateSurface.

A minimal reproductible example won't be easy to produce since it may imply a lot of code to be reproductible. If few code would be necessary to reproduce that problem, it would have been since 50 years that everybody would talk about that :P

The process of reducing erroneous code to an MRE is what you would do when debugging anyway: take away parts that should not contribute to the error, until you suddenly remove a part and it starts working.

@Botje yeh for sure, but in fact I even created PointData and pushback 3 arbitrary points just before calling the function and had the problem ^^ so part of code seems not to contribute to that... neverless, I edited the question for the code between those part

ImageOfCreateObjectJustBefore
I confirm that this makes the same problem...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

to the record, we discovered with @Botje that offsetof(PointsData, y); have different value in the lib calling the function, and in the other function from the lib

My temporary solution is to work in Release with debug info. It permits me to run with debugging
